# shell parallel programing with error control

Tags: linux, shell

Here is my code (learn form the book Linux shell scripting cookbook)

```
#/bin/bash

PIDARRAY=()

(echo aaa >> /dev/null;sleep 8; exit 0)&
PIDARRAY+=("$!")
(echo bbb >> /dev/null;sleep 4;echo helloworld; exit 1)&
PIDARRAY+=("$!")
(echo ccc >> /dev/null;sleep 16; exit 0)&
PIDARRAY+=("$!")


wait ${PIDARRAY[@]}
```

$! save the last bg task pid,so the PIDARRAY will save three bg task pid,I try to achive this:one task failed,kill the other two and exit the shell,but failed ,Here is my modify code:

```
#/bin/bash

PIDARRAY=()

(echo aaa >> /dev/null;sleep 100; exit 0)&
PIDARRAY+=("$!")
(echo bbb >> /dev/null;sleep 4;echo helloworld; exit 1)&
PIDARRAY+=("$!")
(echo ccc >> /dev/null;sleep 100; exit 0)&
PIDARRAY+=("$!")

wait ${PIDARRAY[@]}

if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    kill -9 PIDARRAY[0]
    kill -9 PIDARRAY[1]
    kill -9 PIDARRAY[2]
fi
```

there is one obvious error,if one task failed ,we need only kill another two task,not three,I put the if statement before and after wait,got not what I want,How can I achive my goal:one task failed,kill the other two and exit the shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use **GNU Parallel** for efficiently managing parallel tasks. So, in your case:

```
parallel --halt now,fail=1 ::: task1 task2 task3
```

There are a million ways to submit jobs, so you could store your job-list in a file called `jobs`:

```
echo aaa >> /dev/null;sleep 100; exit 0
echo bbb >> /dev/null;sleep 4;   echo helloworld; exit 1
echo ccc >> /dev/null;sleep 100; exit 0
```

and then run like this:

```
parallel --halt now,fail=1 < jobs
```

**Output**

```
helloworld
parallel: This job failed:
echo bbb >> /dev/null;sleep 4;   echo helloworld; exit 1
```

Comment: thanks for your answer,I search and learn about GNU Parallel.

Comment: thans for your answer again,this demo shell scripts passed,In my project,there are three task parallel,the out put to the std out is mixed,what if there are errors,how to show the errors exactly.

Comment: Try `parallel --tag` and `parallel --joblog log.txt` or look in the tutorial https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Comment: If you could be a little more specific about your scripts, you would probably get a better answer as Ole Tange, who develops and maintains GNU Parallel, works hard on Stack studiously assisting users.